# Generalizing tug-of-war puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

A puzzle at the end of a [3Blue1Brown video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBnnXbOM5S4) asks the following question (paraphrased):

> From a group of 20 people, you get to send one person to participate in a tug-of-war tournament. You don't care too much who you send, as long as you don't send the *weakest* person. Each person has a different strength, but you don't know what it is. You get 10 tug-of-war matches of 10 vs. 10 among the group of 20 to determine who to send. How do you make sure you don't send the weakest person?

I won't spoil the solution to the puzzle, but it will likely come as no surprise that the (or at least, my) solution works for any group of $2n$ people, where you get $n$ matches of $n$ vs. $n$ people.

Can you do any *better*, for sufficiently large $n$?

> Is there an $n$ such that you can find a non-weakest person among a group of $2n$ people, using only $n - 1$ tug-of-war matches of $n$ vs. $n$?

And, if this question has an obvious answer I did not think of, can we even characterize the behaviour?

> Let $L(k)$ be the least number of matches required to find a non-weakest person among $2k$ people. What is the asymptotic behaviour of $L$?

Comment: Can team composition (i.e. how to divide into two teams) for round $k$ depend on previous results?  If so, I think I have a $\Theta(\log_2 n)$ solution.  In fact I think it is $1 + \log_2 n$.

Comment: @antkam, I definitely think it can, and intended my question this way, although my solution to the original puzzle does not require it -- so perhaps it makes for another interesting puzzle.

Comment: (1) Curious about your spoiler: Is it equivalent to sitting the people in a circle, the red team being half the circle, and in each round shifting the red team by $1$ person clockwise?  :)  (2) I agree that if team membership in all rounds must be fixed before any matches, the problem is much tougher.  Off the top of my head, I can't think of anything that works in $<n$ rounds in that model, but it might be possible...?

Comment: @antkam, that was indeed my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes we can decide how to divide into two teams for round $k$ based on previous rounds' results.

Notations: Let $X, Y$ be sets of people.  I will abuse notation a bit and write $X+Y$ for their combined strength.  Also, suppose $X$ consists of $n$ people, then a match can be held vs the other half, which I denote as the complement $X^c$.  Further suppose $X$ wins this match.  I will write $X > X^c$, or $X > 1/2$ meaning $X$ has more than half the total strength.  In other words, $X$ will stand for the set if set-theoretic operations are performed (unions, etc), but $X$ will actually stand for the total strength of the people $\in X$ if arithmetic operations are performed.

Assume for now $n = 2^b$ for integer $b$.  Here is a solution that requires $1+b$ rounds.

First partition the $2n$ people into $4$ equal sets $A, B, C, D$ each of size $n/2$.

Round $0$: $A \cup B$ vs $C \cup D$.

Round $1$: $A \cup C$ vs $B \cup D$.

One of the groups has to win twice, and wolog assume it is $A$.  Then we have $A + B > 1/2 > B + D$.

Define a triplet of subsets $(X,Y,Z)$ to be an $m$-triplet if (1) the $3$ sets are disjoint, (2) they have sizes $(m, m, n-m)$ respectively, and (3) $X+ Z > 1/2 > Z + Y$.  So at the end of Round $1, (A,D,B)$ is an ${n\over 2}$-triplet.

The recurrence step will be of this format:  Suppose we have an $m$-triplet $(X, Y, Z)$.  Divide $X$ into $X_1, X_2$ each of size $m/2$, and $Y$ into $Y_1, Y_2$ each of size $m/2$.  Now match up $W = X_1 \cup Y_2 \cup Z$ vs $W^c$.

- Case 1: If $W$ wins, then $W = X_1 + Y_2 + Z > 1/2$.  But we know $1/2 > Y + Z = Y_1 + Y_2 + Z$.  So we now have a new  ${m\over 2}$-triplet $(X_1, Y_1, Z \cup Y_2)$.
- Case 2: If $W$ loses, then $W = X_1 + Y_2 + Z < 1/2$.  But we know $X + Z = X_1 + X_2 + Z > 1/2$.  So we now have a new  ${m\over 2}$-triplet $(X_2, Y_2, Z \cup X_1)$.

So with one match, we reduced an $m$-triplet to an ${m\over 2}$-triplet.

Starting with $n = 2^b$ (recall there were $2n$ people total), after the first $2$ matches we have a $2^{b-1}$-triplet, and the exponent drops by $1$ every additional match.  After $b-1$ more matches we have a $2^0$-triplet, i.e. a $1$-triplet $(F,G,H)$ where $F+H > 1/2 > G+H$.  But this implies $F > G$, and since each set contains only one person, we know the person in $F$ is not the weakest since the person in $G$ is weaker.

Total number of matches $= b + 1 = 1 + \log_2 n$.

---

If $n$ is not a power of $2$, the procedure is a bit messier, but we ultimately still rely on the same recurrence.  If $m$ is odd, we divide $X$ and $Y$ as evenly as possible, where  the sizes of $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are $\lceil {m\over 2} \rceil$.  Then in case 1 we get a new $\lceil {m\over 2} \rceil$-triplet whereas in case 2 we get a new $\lfloor {m \over 2} \rfloor$-triplet.  Clearly the total number of matches $= 1 + \lceil \log_2 n \rceil$.

Comment: nice! And in a way you could see this as a generalization of my solution. If $n = ab$, with $a, b > 1$ integers, you can first do the sliding window around the table in $b$ steps of $a$ people. Once you know where the jump is you need only $b - 1$ sliding window steps to get the exact person. Two more observations: you can iterate this, so if $b = a'b'$ you can reduce steps further; and $ab$ only needs to be an upper bound of $n$, not an exact product. Then your solution is this method applied to the product decomposition $n \leq 2^{\lceil \log_2(n) \rceil}$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries - that's exactly the picture I had in mind.  First I found your "circle, shift-by-1" solution.  Then I convinced myself shift-by-2 works.  Then it's pretty obvious to try either shift-by-$\sqrt{n}$ or binary-search.  I tried the latter and it worked.  For the written Answer above, I just decided the set-based presentation is easier than the circle-based presentation, but in fact I _think_ we can line up all the $X$s and $Y$s and $Z$s at all levels of the recursion in a line, and show it is "embeddable" into a circle, so to speak.